# Can I use my "chainstate" folder for anything?

Tags: bitcoin-core, database

I've recently found an old folder called "chainstate" in my PC.
Can't remember why I saved it but inside it there's the following files:
"000003.log"
"CURRENT"
"LOCK"
"MANIFEST-000002"

Are these of any use at all? Could I access an old wallet using these? What does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

The chainstate directory stores publicly available data, [specifically](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_Core_0.11_(ch_2):_Data_Storage) unspent transaction outputs and some metadata at the time it was saved. It doesn't contain any private key material and so it can't be used to claim or send any funds.